# Can I use gitg to see the changes only on one file/directory?

Tags: git, gitg

This is driving me crazy, as it's very easy on gitk (just `gitk the/file`) but I am not able to do it on gitg which I really like to see the history.

It's not a well documented tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no it can't do that (in v0.0.6).

[gitg](http://freshmeat.net/projects/gitg) claims:

> gitg does not aim to be an advanced
>   tool that allows access to every
>   feature of Git through a graphical
>   interface. However, it will try to
>   incorporate common actions that might
>   require multiple actions on the
>   command line (like staging, unstaging,
>   reverting, and committing)

Your best bet is the command line `git log <file>` or `gitk <file>`

Comment: I believe there's a typo: Did you mean `gitk <file>`?